# get list of unavailable values from table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table in sql server 2008 ,with hospital id's and their departments:

```
HID    DEPT
5   neuro
2   derma
3   cardio
2   ent
1   neuro
5   optha
3   ent
3   optha
4   derma
1   optha
5   derma
```

Need to get the list of id's and department names that it doesn't have, using sql.
eg:

```
HID   DEPT
 1    derma
 1    cardio
 1    ent
 2    cardio
 2    neuro
 2    optha
```

etc. Thank you

Comment: How do you know which one it doesn't have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT HID
            FROM YourTable) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DEPT
                FROM YourTable) B
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
                 WHERE HID = A.HID AND DEPT = A.DEPT)
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dac0a/2) an sqlfiddle with a demo.

Comment: Thank you very much Lamak. It worked. Could you plz tell me what 'select 1 from' does ?

Comment: @Ruby the `EXISTS` verifies that some row is returned, it doesn't matter if it's `SELECT 1`, `SELECT *`, `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT whatevercolumn`. I find that `SELECT 1` makes it clearer that I don't want any column from that `SELECT`, I'm only checking existence

Answer (score 3):

For this type of query, you want to start with a "driver" subquery that generates all possible combinations.  You then do a `left outer join` to the ones that exist, and select the ones that do not match:

```
select driver.hid, driver.dept
from (select hid, dept
      from (select distinct hid from hd) h cross join
           (select distinct dept from hd) d
     ) driver left outer join
     hd
     on driver.hid = hd.hid and
        driver.dept = hd.dept
where hd.hid is null;
```

EDIT:

This is the corrected query with data:

```
with hd as (
      select 5 as hid, 'neuro' as dept union all
      select 2, 'derma' union all
      select 3, 'cardio' union all
      select 2, 'ent' union all
      select 1, 'neuro' union all
      select 5, 'optha' union all
      select 3, 'ent' union all
      select 3, 'optha' union all
      select 4, 'derma' union all
      select 1, 'optha' union all
      select 5, 'derma'
     )
select driver.hid, driver.dept
from (select hid, dept
      from (select distinct hid from hd) h cross join
           (select distinct dept from hd)d
     ) driver left outer join
     hd
     on driver.hid = hd.hid and
        driver.dept = hd.dept
where hd.hid is null;
```

Note that it returns a longer list than in the question.  I think that list is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you. It says: Incorrect syntax near keyword cross and near syntax near ')' [line5]. Also tried just '(select distinct hid from hd) cross join
           (select distinct dept from hd)....but gives the same error

Comment: @Ruby . . . The error message was due to missing aliases on the subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

To make the list of options more complete, here's also an EXCEPT solution:

```
SELECT h.HID, d.DEPT
FROM       (SELECT HID  FROM atable) h
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DEPT FROM atable) d
EXCEPT
SELECT HID, DEPT
FROM atable;
```

Depending on how many times values are repeated in either of the columns, you could also try cross joining only unique values before applying EXCEPT:

```
SELECT h.HID, d.DEPT
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT HID  FROM atable) h
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DEPT FROM atable) d
EXCEPT
SELECT HID, DEPT
FROM atable;
```